# Open CSS3 / HTML5 modal dialog relative to mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a modal dialog using CSS3, it works perfectly. But my site is responsive and the modal has to appear on several items inside an iframe (see here: http://labs.tageswoche.ch/interaktives/filmPortraits/ and here: http://master.tw.felix.sourcefabric.net/de/2014_11/international/652865/Drei-Jahre-B%C3%BCrgerkrieg-und-kein-Ende-in-Sicht.htm). In the iframe it doesnt work, but it works as expected on the real site.

The modal dialog is implemented on the first two pictures.

And here the code:

```
.modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
width: 400px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
background: #606061;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
background: #00d9ff;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle I used to implement the modal dialog:

http://jsfiddle.net/kumarmuthaliar/GG9Sa/1/

What i want to achieve is that the modal appears where the mouse click was (or more or less) so that also on mobile devices on the last images of the wall. Right now the modal appears on top. How can I implement this? I have no clue.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'd like to say about your design is, do not make separate modal window htmls for each person's modal, use one modal and change its innerhtml as you click on different people so you write less code, easier to maintain (if you add changes to your modal, you do one change in one location etc)

Also, the nature of modal windows is, it has a semi transparency background, with the modal window floating (not in css context) in the middle of it.

If you see this css bit below you'll understand better:

```
.modalDialog > div {
width: 600px;
position: relative;
margin: 5% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
background: #fff;
}
```

The bit that says "margin: 5% auto;" causes this behaviour, what you need to do is change this to the same notation the padding is set and for each position of the image, give it certain values, ie margin: 10px 10px for a modal window that just shows at the top left corner of the window etc if you're not too fussy about exact mouse location.

If you are, than use "onclick" event of your outermost background div with width/height equal to the overall size of every person's image included, than use the event object to get mouse location values (read this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp)

I didn't write it for you so that you can do it yourself and learn, hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer. I realised that I need a function to detect the mouse position and then position the modal div accordingly. Unfortunately, i dont know how, but i try my best. Help is appreciated, though!